# mongoose query works in mongo shell but not in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to execute the query from my node.js-express application.The query is not returning any result. But when I execute the query in the mongodb shell it shows the expected result.

My code is:

```
var query = commentModel.Comment.find({
    "$and": [
           {
               "type": {
                   "$in": [
                       207,208,209
                   ]
               }
           },
           {
               "trs": {
                   "$ne": 3
               }
           },
           {
               "$or": [
                   {
                       "status": {
                           "$in": [
                               1,
                               2
                           ]
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       "$and": [
                           {
                               "status": 3
                           },
                           {
                               "UID": req.session.userId
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }).skip(this.index).limit(this.count);
console.log("Query  : "+ JSON.stringify(query));
query.exec(function(err, result) {
console.log("Result Length :"+result.length+" Error:"+err);
    if( (err) || (result.length == 0)) {
        console.log("Result Length :"+result.length+" Error:"+err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Success Result Length :"+result.length+" Error:"+err);
    }
});
```

When I print the query to console

> Query  : {"options":{"populate":{}},"_conditions":{"$and":[{"type":{"$in":[207,208,209]}},{"trs":{"$ne":3}},{"$or":[{"status":{"$in":[1,2]}},{"$and":[{"status":3},{"UID":14}]}]}]},"_updateArg":{},"op":"find"}

I use the _condition from this and execute it in mongodb shell as

```
>db.tbl_comment.find({"$and":[{"type":{"$in":[207,208,209]}},{"trs":{"$ne":3}},{"$or":[{"status":{"$in":[1,2]}},{"$and":[{"status":3},{"UID":14}]}]}]})
```

Here in the shell it displaying the result. I don't know what is missing...

Comment: Just to check the basics, are you sure you are connected to the same mongo server and database name between your app and the console?

Comment: Yes.everything else is working...adding,deleting,updating..etc.And there is only one db in my application.

Comment: Mongoose may be casting one of the fields in your query to another type based on your schema.  To see the actual query being run, enable Mongoose debugging by adding this to your code: `mongoose.set('debug', true);`

Comment: Wouldn't it be just `commentModel.find`?

Comment: Thanks  JohnnyHK..i got it...thanks to all..
@theabraham : no it is commentModel.Comment.find in my case...thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyHK you may be long gone from stack overflow, but if you're still around you should post your comment as the answer. Solved my problem, thanks!